# SQL result show empty results in phpmyadmin xampp

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

**i have make a login and register page in php and every thing work fine and it show me that user register successful .**

my question is that when i navigate to `localhost/phpmyadmin` and try to get the user and password i just entered it so i use :

> SELECT*FROM "my-table-name";

show me this response

---

> Host: 127.0.0.1
>
> Database: data base name
>
> Generation Time: Jun 15, 2015 at 07:34 PM
>
> Generated by: phpMyAdmin 4.3.11 / MySQL 5.6.24
>
> SQL query: SELECT * FROM `table name` LIMIT 0, 25 ;
>
> Rows: 1

and print a table with id = 1 and every thing else empty username , email and  password

```
the database structure
```

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
>
> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>
> `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
>
> UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
>
> UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
>
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: clearly your code dosen't work properly, posting some code will definitely help, i'll also suggest you check whether you're getting your values properly from your registration form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for spelling errors in your Form and your SQL Statement. Also, consider making your username/email field/s non-nullable as a good practice.

Comment: a message show this

Notice in .\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php#55
 Undefined variable: server

Backtrace

.\libraries\structure.lib.php#2452: include(.\libraries\tbl_columns_definition_form.inc.php)
.\tbl_structure.php#45: PMA_displayHtmlForColumnChange(
string 'database_name',
string 'table_name',
NULL,
string 'tbl_structure.php',
)